# Is there any way for fl chart's LineChart to not plot line and dot, skip it, if value of y axis is 0?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, linechart, fl-chart

good day everyone.
I am currently using FL Chart for our flutter app.

Is there any way for fl chart's LineChart to not plot line and dot, skip it, if the value of y-axis is 0? So the line will just go to the next point where the value of y-axis is not 0?

For reference:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I hope you could help me.

fl_chart VERSION: ^0.63.0
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zMi4.png